# Firebase Trigger Format

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've successfully gotten my console to trigger a function in Firebase every day at 12:00. But, how do I trigger the function only on weekdays?

This is what I currently have:

```
0 12 * * *
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions use [App Engine's cron.yaml format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref) for their schedule descriptions.

Searches on [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=cron.yaml+weekday&oq=cron.yaml+weekday) leads to:

```
every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 12:00
```